# awk to output unique count of text in field

Tags: awk

I am trying to output the count of the **unique text** in the input file.  It is in `$2` but I can only seem to get a count of 1 using the below.  Thank you :).

```
awk '{sub(/:.*/,"",$2)} !seen[$5]++{unq++} END{print unq}' input.txt > output.txt
```

**input.txt**

```
chrX:48544112-48544235 **WAS**:exon.1;WAS:exon.4;WAS:exon.6 271.171
chr5:1282528-1282754 **TERT**:exon.1;TERT:exon.3 349.08
chrX:48547038-48547465 **WAS**:exon.1;WAS:exon.10;WAS:exon.2 42.459
```

**Desired output**

```
2
```

Comment: Why `!seen[$5]++` and not `!seen[$2]++`?

Comment: What are you counting?  **WAS**, **TERT** etc?

Comment: That was it, I forgot to change the field from another `awk`.  Is there a way to combine all the `$2` on one line separated by a comma that match in a file.  I will update the post as well.  Thank you :).

Comment: I am counting WAS, TERT as the names.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you redefine your field separator to "colon or space", it gets a lot simpler

```
awk -F '[: ]' '!seen[$3]++ {n++} END {print n}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

alternative non-awk solution

```
 tr ':' ' ' <file | cut -d' ' -f3 | sort | uniq -c | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

The Perl version is a bit ugly since it uses `$F[2]` vs awk's `$3`

```
perl -F'[: ]' -lane '$n++ if ! $seen{$F[2]}++; END{print $n}' file
```